# Android: Custom Background Color for ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've read many posts on this problem, but none have helped. Can someone explain why my project will not change the background color of my Action Bar? The docs say to include support library compatibility, via

```
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>,
```

however, I don't know how to specify just a color for the drawable. Putting #57d1a3 here gives an error. I'm not even sure this would solve my problem.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Main Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And finally, styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#57d1a3</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: If you are using android lollipop, you should apply "colorPrimary". Refer to http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can make a simple drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#YOUR_OWN_COLOR"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: OK, close. The app launches and I see the changed color. Then the app immediately crashes. There is no code in the app other than what I posted. The error I get is "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. You are using the appcompact to support older verstion, I do not so you get that crash. Instead of this Theme.Holo.Light you need your appcompact, let me google it quick

Comment: Got it to work by keeping my styles xml, but using your drawable. Thanks!

Comment: My min SDK is 15. Do I even need AppCompat? I guess the point is that I can't avoid it if I need v7 support for other things?

Comment: No, actionbar is present since v11. Is there any specific reason why 15 and not 14? By supporting 14 you are supporting 90% of devices anyway...

Comment: Glad Bojan fixed your issue. As a developer myself, I recommend you get used to v7 and start using a toolbar. That is...if you care about design guidelines and such.

Comment: @AndrewQuebe if you care about design, then you are porabably going to make your UI compenents anyway... including your own actionbar since the original one is only somewhat functional.

Comment: I'm going to agree with Andrew and Bojan about making your own UI components (or using ToolBar in this case). The action bar implementation is clunky at best.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code in styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
      parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
  </style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style name="MyActionBar"
      parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
      <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">#57d1a3</item>
       <item name="background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/myColor</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I've tried this. It produces an error - "Can't resolve symbol #57d1a3"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using AppCompat for theming, the answer is really simple. Don't use an Action Bar but instead, a [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.htmlhttps://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). Below is an example of how to define a Toolbar in XML, and set it up in your activity with color.

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fb_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

YourActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feedback_activity);

    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.fb_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);

    //Parse a color with any hex code
    tb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    //Set title
    tb.setTitle("Your title");
}
```

This should make a Toolbar with a background color of white and a title of "Your Title".

## Edit:

Here's a snippet of styles.xml which I use for one of my apps. It uses a toolbar and navigation drawer so some of it can be ignored.

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppThemeNavDrawer" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#F8F8F8</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarCustomIconColor" parent="AppThemeNavDrawer">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/drawer_list_selector</item>
</style>
```